# Text ellipsis doesn't show on flexbox item

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I've tested `text-overflow: ellipsis` on chrome and firefox and both have shorten the text, but it just doesn't show the `'...'` at the end. What is wrong with it?

I have tried using other solutions I found here such as `min-width`, `max-width`, `flex: 0 1 auto`, etc.. But none of them seem to be working. The ellipsis doesn't show up.

This is my code:

```
ul {
  display: flex;
  height: 40px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  list-style: none;
}
ul li {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0 4px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
}
ul li:first-child {
  width: 55px;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}
ul li:first-child input {
  width: 100%;
}
ul li:last-child {
  width: 48px;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}
ul li:nth-child(2) {
  flex: 0 1 auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  min-width: 0px;
}
ul li:nth-child(3) {
  width: 75px;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}
```

Here is a fiddle to demonstrate the problem: https://jsfiddle.net/dpbejpou/1/

> Note: I already tried using others solutions, like I said, such as min-width, max-width (which you can see already is in my code) found [on this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31069474/text-overflow-in-combination-with-flexbox-not-working) but the code stil doesn't work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [text-overflow in combination with flexbox not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31069474/text-overflow-in-combination-with-flexbox-not-working), but you also need an inner wrapping element: https://jsfiddle.net/dpbejpou/2/

Comment: @Pete like I said in the question, I already used the `min-width` solution, which already is in the code but still doesn't work. This is why I made a new question.

Comment: @Pete i do not think so, here we have displayflex; + text-overflow on same tag, wich is not compatible (and somehow not coherent , it is flex and it can eventually wrap), i guess display:table/table-cell and table-layout will handle this

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/dpbejpou/3/ table layout to see behavior. your flexbox item is also a flexbox , you should edit your title question, so no one gets confused about this ;)

Comment: @GCyrillus with table I had this working, but I was trying to keep with pure flexbox.. I'm starting to think to go back with table. But your code seems a greate alternative!

Comment: I have shared some solution and removed display flex from li and it is working now. https://jsfiddle.net/dpbejpou/7/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `text-overflow: ellipsis` to work, you must have a width defined. You have `flex-basis: auto`, which is not enough.

Also, `text-overflow: ellipsis` only works on block-level elements.

A flex item is considered [*blockified*](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-items) and ellipsis will work. However, you're also applying `display: flex` to the flex items, which breaks the block-level rule for the `display` property.

Try these adjustments:

```css
ul {
  display: flex;
  height: 40px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  list-style: none;
}
ul li {
  /* display: flex;           <-- remove */
  /* align-items: center;     <-- will no longer work */
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0 4px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
}
ul li:first-child {
  width: 55px;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}
ul li:first-child input {
  width: 100%;
}
ul li:last-child {
  width: 48px;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}
ul li:nth-child(2) {
  flex: 0 1 100px;              /* adjusted; 100px for demo only */
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  min-width: 0px;
}
ul li:nth-child(3) {
  width: 75px;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><input type="number" value="1"></li>
  <li>A very long text description goes here</li>
  <li>$99.90</li>
  <li>Del</li>
</ul>
```

[**Revised Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/dpbejpou/10/)

To vertically center the text, you could use flex layout on the non-ellipsis elements, like you had before. To vertically center the ellipsis text, [try another method](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8865458/3597276).

References:

- [Applying an ellipsis to multiline text](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33058004/3597276)
- [How do I vertically center text with CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8865458/how-to-vertically-center-text-with-css)

Comment: You had an awesome explanation. Thank you so much! I already know how to proceed now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this one [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ugyt8kLa/1/)

A span added to markup:

```
<ul>
  <li><input type="number" value="1"></li>
  <li><span>A very long text description goes here</span></li>
  <li>$99.90</li>
  <li>Del</li>
</ul>
```

And just this css:

```
ul li:nth-child(2) span {
    max-width: 135px; //change it to any max value you like
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to remove the display flex property of li. Please check the demo.

```
ul li {
  align-items: center;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0 4px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
}
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/dpbejpou/7/)